# Upload a file with ajax post in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I want to upload a file as sending an email if user choose a file. Here is my code;

```
  function SendCollectiveMail() {


        var despatchTypeId = $("#DespatchTypeId").val();
        var despatchGroupId = $("#DespatchGroupId").val();
        var despatchBalanceId = $("#BalanceOptionId").val();
        if (despatchBalanceId === "")
            despatchBalanceId = 0;

        var blokId = $("#BlockId").val();

        if (blokId === "")
            blokId = 0;


        var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#EndDate").val();
        var subject = $("#Subject").val();
        var aciklama = $("#Detail").val();

        var uploads = "";

        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

            formData.append("FileUpload", file);
        }

        if (totalFiles > 0) {

            alert('Dosya sunucuya yüklendi.' + formData);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Upload/UploadFile',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    uploads = response.result;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("SendCollectiveMail", "CollectiveMail")',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "_despatchTypeId": despatchTypeId, "_despatchGroupId": despatchGroupId, "_despatchBalanceOptionId": despatchBalanceId, "_blokId": blokId, "_firstDate": startDate, "_lastDate": endDate, "subject": subject, "aciklama": aciklama, "uploads": uploads }),
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.Message);
                        }
                    });
                }, error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);

                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SendCollectiveMail", "CollectiveMail")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "_despatchTypeId": despatchTypeId, "_despatchGroupId": despatchGroupId, "_despatchBalanceOptionId": despatchBalanceId, "_blokId": blokId, "_firstDate": startDate, "_lastDate": endDate, "subject": subject, "aciklama": aciklama, "uploads": uploads }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Sunucu Mesajı: Mail gönderimi başarısız.');
                }
            });
        }




    }
```

And here is my controller code:

```
 public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Upload
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                string uploadedAddresses = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = Request.Files[i];

                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/TempUploads/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    uploadedAddresses += path + ",";
                }

                return Json(new { result = uploadedAddresses });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper();

                using (var con = dataHelper.CustomerConnection())
                {
                    con.Open();

                    var insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Exception]
                                           ([Message])
                                     VALUES
                                           (" + exc.Message + ")";

                    con.Query(insertQuery);
                }

                throw;
            }



        }
    }
```

When I upload a file and call SendCollectiveMail function, I have get `Not Found` error on my `ajax post`. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Pls post your SendCollectiveMail function

Comment: Why are you making 2 separate ajax calls to 2 separate methods (this can all be done in about 1/10 of your code).